# Magento & Android Login Connection

Tags: php, android, magento, session

I am developing an android app (using retrofit) that has users login onto the frontend of a magento based website using their account login details (using a custom controller/extension).

data is POST using retrofit in android

loginAction Magento ..

```
       $session->login($email, $password);         
       if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())  {
                $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

                $result['result'] = 'success';
                $result['message'] = $this->__('Successfully Authorized User '.$customer->getFirstname());

                $getUser["name"] = $customer->getFirstname();
                $getUser["email"] = $customer->getEmail();
                $getUser["unique_id"] = $customer->getId();
                $result["user"] = $getUser;

        }else{

                $result['result'] = 'failure';
                $result['message'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Failed to Auth');

        }
```

Login works and returns success, but doing a logged in check doesn't work

Within the app I have function (onClick) (for dev purposes) to check if current user is logged in and it the result is always false and I can see session files getting created eveytime I do this check, which means that the request is always a new request/new session.

login Check

```
<?php $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();?>
<?php if ($customer) { ?>
   <?php echo '{"result": "success","message": "Access Granted. Authorised"}'; ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
   <?php echo '{"result": "failure","message": "Access Disabled. Not Authorised User"}'; ?>
<?php } ?>

//Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') returns empty
//Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer() returns empty
//Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() returns empty
```

not sure if its Magento or Android using retrofit that's causing new sessions data on each request.

Only alternative I can think of is to POST login details each request to re log the user in to do auth processes ie update user name, update/change email ...